# Where save parent and child model if you need to reuse the code in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, coupling

In a Laravel application, lets say you have a parent model and a child model, and you need to save both in the same procedure and you want to reuse the code.

Where do you save them?

I don't want to save them in a Controller, because I need (and I want) to reuse the code in another Controller.
I could save them in the parent model, but I would like to not increase the coupling between the two models.

Where would you save them? In an helper?

Thanks

Comment: I like to use a PHP traits for this

Comment: Good idea, thanks :)